# Display currency symbols using currency code culture in windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, cultureinfo

Is there a way to get current information dynamically from the apps culture settings? Basically if the user has set the culture to US I want to know the currency is dollars, or if they have it set to UK I want to pound sterling etc.in windows phone 8.

I have one textblock and i want show different currency symbol

Comment: App's culture information or User's culture information? User's culture information determination is trivial - `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. Are you trying to do some form of currency translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution

```
tbCurencysymbol.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol.ToString();
```

***NOTE*:
When you change region in your windows phone 8 so restart is must require